# C# - Default MessageBox.Show() caption

Tags: c#

Is there any way to have a default MessageBox.Show() caption? Let says I would like to have my application name as Message Box caption and I don't want to input MessageBox.Show(msg, ApplicationName) all the time. I just want to call MessageBox.Show(msg).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make Global function like this:

```
static class Global
{
    public static void ShowMyMessage(string msg)
    {
     MessageBox.Show(msg, ApplicationName)   
    }
}
```

now when you want to show message just write:

```
Global.ShowMyMessage("Message");
```

Answer (score 2):

No, but you could write a helper method that does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so.  But why not just create a wrapper function that places this default caption into the MessageBox and they you would just call the wrapper function.

Answer (score 1):

A wrapper function would be best but you could inherit the MessageBox control and find the text from the application's active window.